# What is the replacement of "MessageTeam" in StreamChatReactAPI

Tags: javascript, getstream-chat

***StreamChatAPI v10*** has got new replacement for some API like ***"MessageTeam"***. I have read the documentation but it's difficult to find its replacement.

**First code:**
[image: 1]

**Second code:**
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `stream-chat-react@10.0.0`, the already deprecated `MessageTeam` component was removed from the SDK. Unfortunately, there isn't a drop-in replacement offered by the SDK as we believe MessageUI customizations would be best if handled by the integration projects.

As a starting point, you can take the `MessageTeam` implementation from the latest v9.x release and maintain it in your project. You can find it here:

- https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react/blob/v9.5.2/src/components/Message/MessageTeam.tsx

You can follow this guide in order to instruct the SDK to use your own MessageUI implementation:

- https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/react/message-components/message_ui/

Comment: This works exactly as said. Uninstalled v10x and installed v9.x. Merci beaucoup. Before, I installed v6.x after discovering it was no longer on v10. But to my surprise, v6 couldn't work with React v17.x

Answer (score 0):

go to your terminal --> `npm uninstall stream chat stream-chat-react` it will delete the current version
Then write --> `npm install stream-chat stream-chat-react@9` hit enter

that will definitely solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use MessageSimple from stream-chat-react, this component is almost similar to the MessageTeam.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).